# curl and run python script

Tags: bash, curl

What is a shorter way to do that:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
```

?
I tried this:

```
sudo <(python <(curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py))
```

but it returns the error:
'IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe'

This works: `python <(curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)` but requires `sudo`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python -`

`curl` will output given URL to stdout

`python -` indicate, that source will be taken from stdin.

Comment: `-s` flag (silent) for `curl` should be helpful in case you plan to use that in some automation script or tool, so that it will not blame you with download progress.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to install pip:

`sudo python -m ensurepip`