# Pipe curl output as a python file to python

Tags: python, curl, pipe

I'm trying to run python on a curl output without actually downloading the file onto the system.

So instead of doing the following:

```
wget 1.2.3.4/mypythonfile.py
python mypythonfile.py
```

I'd like to be able to do something like `python | (curl 1.2.3.4/mypythonfile.py)`.

The above command doesn't work by the way.

How would I do that?

Comment: `curl 1.2.3.4/mypythonfile.py | python`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [curl and run python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27273987/curl-and-run-python-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `python | (curl 1.2.3.4/mypythonfile.py)`, do this

```
curl 1.2.3.4/mypythonfile.py | python -
```

Comment: The first solution create a copy of the file on the system. OP ask to avoid that. I think the 2nd one answer that.

Comment: The first option should be removed. Totally redundant.