# How to load a python script from a raw link (such as Pastebin)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pastebin

I have a python script from a Pastebin link such as https://pastebin.com/raw/hz8p3B5Y:

```
import requests
requests.get('https://api.telegram.org/******/sendMessage?chat_id=******&text=*****  # Send notification to my Telegram
```

I want to run a local python script that could load the raw Pastebin and execute it.

Comment: You may use the [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) function.

Answer (score 1):

How about using bash? You could curl then execute the script with Python

```
curl your_url | sudo python -
```

- `curl` will print URL's content to stdout
- `python -` will indicate that source come from from stdin

Related to [curl and run python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27273987/curl-and-run-python-script)

Comment: im using windows btw

Comment: Well... [How to Install and Use the Linux Bash Shell on Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/)

Comment: i have 4 system i need to this its a little a pain :(
is there any other way  ?

maybe a python script that download my raw script and save the file then run it as another python file ?

Comment: @JeanPierreWaked why not. it is python all the way down.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pure Python solution, as compared to the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52588246/2745495) which requires Bash.

First, you can get the raw content of the Pastebin link using `requests` module's [`requests.content`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content):

```
import requests

pastebin_raw_link = 'https://pastebin.com/raw/xxxxxxxx'
response = requests.get(pastebin_raw_link)
source_code = response.content

print(source_code.decode('utf-8'))
```

That should print out the same contents as the "raw" tab of Pastebin
[image: Pastebin raw]

Next, you can run `source_code` by:

- **Option 1**: Calling [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) on it

  ```py
  exec(source_code)
  ```

  This is generally the accepted answer from [How do I execute a string containing Python code in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/701802/2745495) It is also generally considered as unsafe, as discussed in posts such as [Why should exec() and eval() be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1933451/2745495) Make sure you *really really* trust that Pastebin link.
- **Option 2**: Writing it to a [`tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) then using [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) to [import Python modules directly from a source file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly):

  ```py
  import importlib.util
  import sys
  import tempfile

  with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.py') as source_code_file:
      # Should print out something like '/var/folders/zb/x14l5gln1b762gjz1bn63b1sxgm4kc/T/tmp3jjzzpwf.py' depending on the OS
      print(source_code_file.name)

      source_code_file.write(source_code)
      source_code_file.flush()

      # From Python docs recipe on "Importing a source file directly"
      module_name = 'can_be_any_valid_python_module_name'
      spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, source_code_file.name)
      module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
      sys.modules[module_name] = module
      spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  ```

  This is similar to just manually copying the contents of the Pastebin link, pasting it to some file (ex. 'test.py') in the same directory, and then importing it as `import test`, which executes the contents of the file.

  It is also possible to not use `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`, but then you'll have to manually delete the files you create. The `tempfile` module already does that for you: "*the file is deleted as soon as it is closed*".

  Also, the nice thing about importing it as a module, is that it *acts like any other Python module*. Meaning, for example, your Pastebin link declares some variables or methods, then you can do:

  ```
  module.some_variable
  module.call_some_method()
  ```