# How to run a Python code from a Pastebin snippet?

Tags: python

Is there any way to implement a code saved on pastebin in your Python application?

Example:

```
a = 1
# [load pastebin content: a=a+1]
print(a)
```

Is that possible with any command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python load a python script from a raw link (pastebin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52588167/python-load-a-python-script-from-a-raw-link-pastebin)

Comment: You would have to have the text read in from the pastebin to be interpreted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can!

```py
import requests

def pasterun(post):
    url = f"https://pastebin.com/raw/{post}"
    code = requests.get(url).text
    exec(code)

url = 'https://pastebin.com/JRfkiLM8'
*_, post = url.split('/')
pasterun(post)
```