# Load and execute a full python script from a raw link?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exec, raw

I'm facing some problems trying to load a full python script from my pastebin/github pages.

I followed this link, trying to convert the raw into a temp file and use it like a module: [How to load a python script from a raw link (such as Pastebin)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52588167/how-to-load-a-python-script-from-a-raw-link-such-as-pastebin)

And this is my test (Using a really simple python script as raw, my main program is not so simple unfortunately): https://trinket.io/python/0e95ba50c8

When I run the script (that now is creating a temp file in the current directory of the .py file) I get this error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\BOT\\Images\\tempxm4xpwpz.py'
```

Otherwise I also treid the `exec()` function... No better results unfortunately.
With this code:

```
import requests as rq
import urllib.request

def main():
    code = "https://pastebin.com/raw/MJmYEKqh"
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(code)
    data = response.read()
    exec(data)
```

I get this error:

```
  File "<string>", line 10, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in hola
NameError: name 'printest' is not defined
```

Since my program is more complex compared to this simple test, I don't know how to proceed...
Basically What I want to achieve is to write the full script of my program on GitHub and connect it to a .exe so if I upgrade the raw also my program is updated. Avoiding to generate and share (only with my friends) a new .exe everytime...

Do you think is possible? If so.. what am I doing wrong?

PS: I'm also open to other possibilities to let my friends update the program without downloading everytime the .exe, as soon as they don't have to install anything (that's why I'm using .exe).

Comment: From the security standpoint this is horrible idea.

Comment: Hi Klaus, can you please tell me why? My idea was to put the same script on pastebin and github, then the program will compare them, if they're the same then the script will be executed. At least if one of the 2 sites get compromised the program doesn't start.
If you know a better method I'd like to hear it :)
Best, Dario

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: it is really not a good idea to run an unverified (let alone untrusted) code.** That being said if you really want to do it...

Probably the easiest and "least-dirty" way would be to run whole new process. This can be done directly in python. Something like this should work (inspiration from the answer you linked in your question):

```
import urllib.request
import tempfile
import subprocess

code = "https://pastebin.com/raw/MJmYEKqh"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(code)
data = response.read()

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.py') as source_code_file:
    source_code_file.write(data)
    source_code_file.flush()
    subprocess.run(['python3', source_code_file.name])
```

You can also make your code with `exec` run correctly:

**What *may* work:**

- `exec(data, {})` -- All you need to do, is to supply `{}` as second argument (that is use `exec(data, {})`). Function `exec` may receive two additional optional arguments -- globals and locals. If you supply just one, it will use the same directory for locals. That is the code within the `exec` would behave like sort-of "clean" environment, at the top-level. Which is something you aim for.
- `exec(data, globals())` -- Second option is to supply the globals from your current scope. This will also work, though you probably has no need to give the `exec`ucted code access to your globals, given that that code will set-up everything inside anyway

**What does not work:**

- `exec(data, {}, {})` -- In this case the executed code will have two different dictionaries (albeit both empty) for locals and globals. As such it will behavie "as-in" (I'm not really sure about this part, but as I tested it, it seams as such) the function. Meaning that it will add the `printest` and `hola` functions to the local scope instead of global scope. Regardless, I expected it to work -- I expected it will just query the `printest` in the `hola` function from the local scope instead of global. However, for some reason the `hola` function in this case gets compiled in such a way it expects `printest` to be in global scope and not local, which is not there. I really did not figured out why. So this will result in the `NameError`
- `exec(data, globals(), locals())` -- This will provide access to the state from the caller function. Nevertheless, it will crash for the very same reason as in the previous case
- `exec(data)` -- This is just a shorthand for `exec(data, globals(), locals()`

Comment: Hey Drecker thanks a lot for your time! I gonna study more the exec way, since I'm stuck with some terminology (I'm self thaught, that's not helping).
About the script using subprocess, I'm trying it but I have this error:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Also... thinking about the code all of my freinds don't have python installed, will subprocess works for them too? 

I'm starting thinking there is no way to do it entirely in a .exe file :/

Comment: Update:
I renamed python3 in just python and added 'shell=True' in subprocess.run func, solced the first error but got a new one:
[Errno 13] Permission denied

Tried to launch PyCharm as admin but nothing, I think it's something from file side but tbh Idk how to change the permissions :/